What's the difference between long and short (physical shape) type of RJ45 connector of the same specifications?
I have two RJ45 PNs (with builtin magnetics) of different lengths but with same specifications.
I have compared both datasheets but was not able to find any specific difference except the length.

Long RJ45 connector PN - 0826-1X1T-32-F


Short RJ45 connector PN - 7499111446



Any insights on this would be really helpful.

Just the body length after the socket connection where the rj45 plugs in.
This will likely affect the pin pattern for soldering to the board and the securing tags or pins.

So, you mean there is only difference in physical shape and has no difference in electrical Properties, right

@Stannum what were the differences stated on the data sheets?

As per my view, no electrical differences other than physical dimensions.

The bel fuse has a common mode filter on the input, other than that the specs are mostly the same. The bel-fuse is about half the cost of the wurth integrated jack.

Source: https://www.belfuse.com/resources/drawings/magneticsolutions/dr-mag-0826-1x1t-32-f.pdf

Source: https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/7499111446.pdf
If you compare the specs they are mostly the same but the wurth lists crosstalk as a spec while the bel fuse lists CM to DM (you would think they would list a better CM spec than -30dB with their filter but they don't).
So basically half the cost for the bel fuse, pretty much the same.

LED pin numbers appear to be different between the two devices shown.  Also - the Bellfuse device has only a Yellow LED plus Grn/Org LEDs vs Two- Grn/Yel LEDs in the Wurth devices.
